# Operators on $l^{\infty}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Could you tell me how to find norms of these maps?

$$ \phi : l^ {\infty} \ni \{x_n \} \rightarrow \left\{ \frac{x_n}{n} \right\} \in l^2$$

and

$$\phi : l^ {\infty} \ni \{x_n \} \rightarrow \left\{ \frac{x_n}{2^n} \right\} \in l^2$$

How can I use the fact that $\{x_n \}$ is bounded to prove that those maps are well defined and continuous? And if they are, calculate their norms?

Holder inequality gives us:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{|x_n|^2}{n^2} \le \sqrt{\sum \frac{1}{n^2}} \cdot \sqrt{\sum \frac{|x_n|^4}{n^2}}$$

The first series is obviously convergent and the second one also is, because $\{x_n\}$ is bounded.

I guess it will be done similarly in the second case, won't it? Only there we will divide $|x_n|^4$ by $4^n$ and the series will also be convergent.

Is this coreect?

Comment: Those are not functionals, their codomain is not the base field. As for the question try to use Holder's inequality.

Comment: You are right, I'll correct that.

Comment: Hint: basically the "worst" case is that

$
\{x_n\} = \{1,1,1,1,\dots\}.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can get a quick bound on the operators by using some straighforward inequalities. Call our operator $T$. Then $\|T\| = \sup_{\|x_n\|_\infty = 1} \|Tx\|_2$.

Take $\{ x_n \} \in l^\infty$ and suppose that $\|x_n\|_\infty = 1$. We can see that $$\| Tx_n \| = \sqrt{ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|x_n|^2}{n^2} } \le \left(\sup_n |x_n|\right) \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}}=1 \cdot \pi/\sqrt{6}.$$

Thus $\|T\| \le \pi/\sqrt{6}$, and we see that this is actually achieved when $x_n \equiv 1$. Thus $\|T\|=\pi/\sqrt{6}$.

A similar analysis will give you the answer to the second question.

Comment: Made a quick correction here. I missed the square root of the sum. It's just so satisfying to write $\pi^2/6$ for some reason.

Comment: So you are not using Holder inequality here?

Comment: Nope. Not at all. Holder is often handy when you want to discuss $l^p$ spaces, but it is not needed here.

Comment: Good. Thanks a lot!